# Why won't this regex match the to: email address

Tags: java, regex, email

I'm trying to pull an email address out of a string.

Here's my SSCCE:

```
class SSCCE{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Pattern toEmailPattern = Pattern.compile("To: (\\S+)\\s");
            Matcher toMatcher = toEmailPattern.matcher("Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 01:01:44 +0000 (UTC)\n" +
                    "From: TestProjectDoNotChange Do Not Reply <Intds@blah.com>\n" +
                    "To: david1@david1.com\n" +
                    "Message-ID: <1531281253.11415754104803.JavaMail.dallend@P94461>\n" +
                    "Subject: Invitation to DataSite TestProjectDoNotChange ");
            System.out.println(toMatcher.matches()); //false
        }
}
```

For some reason the matcher doesn't find the email address. I'm particularly confused because I've tested my regex out [here](http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/#!;t=Date%3A%20Wed%2C%2012%20Nov%202014%2001%3A01%3A44%20%2B0000%20(UTC)%0AFrom%3A%20TestProjectDoNotChange%20Do%20Not%20Reply%20%3CIntds%40blah.com%3E%0ATo%3A%20david1%40david1.com%0AMessage-ID%3A%20%3C1531281253.11415754104803.JavaMail.dallend%40P94461%3E%0ASubject%3A%20Invitation%20to%20DataSite%20TestProjectDoNotChange%20&r=To%3A%20(%5CS%2B)%5Cs&x=) and that site sayse that it works.

Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, as the javadoc states, [`Matcher#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--)

> Attempts to match the **entire region** against the pattern.

In this case, the entire region is the `String` you've provided when creating the `Matcher`. The regex does not match the full string, but does contain a substring that matches the regex. Use [`Matcher#find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) to find that substring.

Comment: Yep. That was a bit of a sloppy oversight on my part. Thanks for the second pair of eyes. I'll accept once the required time period has passed.